# Collect JVM metrics like heap usages GC info in cloudwatch for fargate services

Tags: heap-memory, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

We are using fargate to deploy our ecs containers. It gives us CPU and Memory utilization dashbaords. We need to capture heap usages pattern/gc/thread usages info for ecs tasks. How could we collect this infor and use cloud watch to set alarnms and monitoring dahsboard on it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We use micrometer to collect our application metrics and Jvm metrics.

Comment: Thats one solution under consideration but i was looking for something from AWS fargate which can directly send these info to cloud watch